# Is there a way to exclude warnings to be reported in Rollbar for Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, warnings, rollbar

Using the Rollbar gem I receive a lot of warnings which consume my event credits, can I exclude them from being reported?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes: in your rollbar config, add them for example:

```
Rollbar.configure do |config|

  config.exception_level_filters.merge!({
    'ActionController::RoutingError' => 'ignore',
  })

end
```

https://github.com/rollbar/rollbar-gem#exception-level-filters

Comment: Thank you @jemminger, I missed that section of the rollbar-gem documentation. Strictly speaking to answer my question I just need 
config.exception_level_filters.merge!({
    'ActionController::RoutingError' => 'ignore'
})
Can you change your answer so I can mark it as accepted?

Comment: @siestetix No problem!